# mysql sum column with same id

Tags: mysql, sum

I have `orders` table, `order_details` table

I join `orders` table with `order_details` table to make a temporary table that look like this

```
order_id | customer_id | Quantity | 
      2  |          2  |    10    | 
      2  |          2  |    25    | 
      2  |          2  |    5     | 
      2  |          2  |    15    | 
      3  |          2  |    25    |
```

What I am trying to achieve is sum `Quantity` column where `order_id` is same.

so the end result look like this

```
order_id | customer_id | Quantity | 
      2  |          2  |    55    | 
      3  |          2  |    25    |
```

my sql statement to get to here look like this

```
SELECT 
        orders.orders_id,
        orders.customer_id_fk,
        sum(order_detail.quantity)
        FROM orders
        LEFT  JOIN order_detail on orders.orders_id = order_detail.orders_id_fk
        WHERE customer_id_fk IN(2)  <-- this is needed because I only want to see customer 2.
```

how do I put a condition on the sum ?

Comment: dear use group by order_id

Comment: Yep I was failing because I had a order by after where and I put group by after order by....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are very close!

You should be able to group by `order_id`to get a list of unique `order_id`s with the `Quantity` sum for each `order_id`

```
SELECT 
 orders.orders_id,
 orders.customer_id_fk,
 sum(order_detail.quantity)
FROM orders
LEFT  JOIN order_detail on orders.orders_id = order_detail.orders_id_fk
WHERE customer_id_fk IN(2)
GROUP BY orders.orders_id,orders.customer_id_fk
```

Answer (score 1):

use Group by

```
SELECT 
        orders.orders_id,
        orders.customer_id_fk,
        sum(order_detail.quantity)
        FROM orders
        LEFT  JOIN order_detail on orders.orders_id = order_detail.orders_id_fk
        WHERE customer_id_fk IN(2) GROUP BY orders.orders_id,orders.customer_id_fk
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is OP. Sorry I derped. I put GROUP BY after Order by and it didnt work. the below sovled it

```
SELECT 
        orders.orders_id,
        orders.customer_id_fk,
        sum(order_detail.quantity)
        FROM orders
        LEFT  JOIN order_detail on orders.orders_id = order_detail.orders_id_fk
        WHERE customer_id_fk IN(2)
        GROUP BY orders_id
        ORDER BY customer_id
```